# What is the proper way to keep scroll position on a listview when switching screens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen which is divided into two 'subpages' by way of a `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl`.

Everything is working great in terms of sliding between the two screens and displaying the different types of data.

##### Except

When I slide between the two pages, or screens, each respective `listview` resets back to the top of the screen and doesn't remember where it was previously.  I'm sure there is something very structurally wrong with my design for this to be happening, but I'm not sure what is the reason for this.

Any clues?  I'm suspecting both screens are just entirely rebuilding when using the segmented control so its essentially an all new list?

```
(...)
child: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
                                    children: {
                                      0: Text('Local News')
                                      1: Text('World News'),
                                    },
                                    groupValue: _sliding,
                                    onValueChanged: (newValue) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _sliding = int.parse(newValue.toString());
                                      });
                                    }),
(...)
child: _processSwitch(_sliding),
```

```
  _processSwitch(_index) {
        return _children(_index);
    }
```

```
  Widget _children(_index){
    List<Widget> pageScreen=[];
    pageScreen.add(LocalNewsScreen());
    pageScreen.add(WorldNewsScreen());
    return pageScreen[_index];
  }
```

Each of my screens is actually a `listview.builder`

##### LocalNewsScreen() and WorldNewsScreen()

```
(...)
child:
      ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

return (... lots of UI elements ..)

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin in the page that contains listview, it will keep the state of that page while switching pages:

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return 
  }
}
```